# complex exponential function $\sin^3(z)=1^{1/3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

It's asking for the values of z.

$$\sin^3(z)=1\\
\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=1^{1/3}$$

and try to leave $e^{iz} $ alone but i have nothing in my hands cannot get rid of that $e^{-iz}$ and result has to be in principal log form.

Comment: Try to use the fact $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2.$ Also as I noticed you title and body does not match with each others.

Comment: Let $u=e^{iz}$ first. Then $u-u^{-1}=2i\cdot 1^{1/3}$. Solve a quadratic equation for $u$.